# Debug text to file formatting

Tags: vb.net, math, rounding

Hey all I am looking to simplify the following code in order to output the correct amount of **=** to match the top/bottom of the output section.

Example:

```
========================================================================
=======================This would be the text here======================
========================================================================
```

The text *This would be the text here* would be what would be sent to the function. This can be anything from 4 characters to a max of 72. I would like to see if there is a more simple way of coding this then the following that I am using:

```
Dim cnt As Integer = 0
Dim ch As Char = ""

For Each c As Char In _tmpDebugArray(0)
    If c = ch Then cnt += 1
Next

cnt = Math.Round((cnt - 72) / 2, 2)
```

**cnt** would give me the amount of **=** that I would need to use on the left and right side of the debug information name to match the top/bottom of the output section's **=**.

Example:

```
Dim strDebug string = "Bob The Builder"
cnt = 72 - strDebug          '72-15 = 57
cnt = Math.Round(cnt / 2, 2) '57/2 = 29 (28.5 rounded)
```

So in the above example the **=** would have **28** on the left then the debug string **Bob The Builder** and then **29** **=**'s on the right side of it. Though this tends to be off by *1* here and there depending on how long the debug string is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be easier to have a fixed width instead and pad the text on the left and right.

```
Sub DisplayText(ByVal text As String)

    Const WIDTH As Integer = 72
    Const DISPLAY_CHAR As String = "="c

    Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(WIDTH, DISPLAY_CHAR))
    Console.WriteLine(text.PadLeft((WIDTH + text.Length) / 2, DISPLAY_CHAR).PadRight(WIDTH, DISPLAY_CHAR))
    Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(WIDTH, DISPLAY_CHAR))

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks, the_lotus.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will only be viewing these strings in a fixed width font, you can use `PadLeft` and `PadRight` to pad your string to the right length. The following function does that with any string, padding character and length.

```
Function PadStringCentre(str As String, ch As Char, len As Integer) As String
    Dim numLeft As Integer = (len - str.Length) \ 2 + str.Length 
    Dim numRight As Integer = len - str.Length - numRight 
    Return str.PadLeft(numLeft,ch).PadRight(len, ch)
End Function
```

You could call it like this

```
Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = PadStringCentre("Bob The Builder", "="c, 72)
End Sub
```